Rmarkdown Cross-references with flextable not working in html
I'm trying to cross-reference tables in an HTML Rmarkdown output.
I'm using both kable and flextable.
In HTML output flextable cross-reference is not working anymore. It works if the output is a PDF
A reproducible example and session info are at the following link
https://rpubs.com/stebif68/1236124
The Rmd is:
---
title: "reproducible example"
date: "2023-04-13"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: default
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set
library(tidyverse)

library(flextable)
library(officer)
```

```{r, echo=F}
sessionInfo()
```

Table \@ref(tab:test) with kable is working in both html & pdf

```{r test, echo=TRUE}

kableExtra::kable(tibble(variable= "hello", another = "bye"), caption = "The mtcars data.")

```

Table \@ref(tab:tab2) with flextable in html in not working

```{r ft.align="center", tab.cap='airquality dataset', tab.id='tab2', label='tab2', echo=T}
ft <- flextable(head(airquality))
# ft <- set_caption(ft, "airquality dataset", 
#   autonum = run_autonum(seq_id = "tab", bkm = "airquality6"))
ft
```



could you try with the dev version of flextable available on github ?

David, Thanks so much, the problem was solved!
